# What Azure App Services can run on the same App Service Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to reduce the number of one-off App Service Plans my organisation has for a number of App Services. However, when clicking "Change App Service plan" within the App Service, often the App Service Plan I would like to move it to doesn't show up in the list.

What determines whether two app services can run on the same App Service Plan besides region? Is it just the Operating System, or also the stack? Does it have something to do with the resource group of either the App Service Plan or App service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About change app service plan, there is a description in the office document: [Move an app to another App Service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan).

About your problem, you said the target plan is not listed in the list, the most likely reason is that they are not in same App Service Environment. In the document it say all plans created with the same resource group and region combination are deployed into the same webspace.

So make sure your App Service Environments are same, like region and resource group before moving web. Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[Free has 10 and Shared has a quota of 100](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/).

Think out how you want to group your applications though as keep in mind they will share the same compute resources if combining.  Also if deploying infrastructure as code keep in mind now that there are more dependencies when combining the applications into one App Service Plan.